# NoReverseMatch Django Tutorial 1.8 chapter 4

Tags: python, django

So I'm also getting the noReverseMatch error at the very end of the 4th chapter of the Django tutorial. But none of the other answers seems to help out in my case. And I can't understand why the tutorial would provide something that doesn't work.

I type everything myself, so there could certainly be a typo somewhere, but I've tried exchanging all the code with copy/paste from chapter 4, and I'm still getting the same error:

Here is the error:

```
NoReverseMatch at /polls/
Reverse for 'detail' with arguments '('',)' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: [u'polls/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/$']

Error during template rendering

In template /home/MyName/tutorial/mysite/polls/templates/polls/index.html, error at line 4
Reverse for 'detail' with arguments '('',)' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: [u'polls/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/$']
```

Here is urls.py:

```
    from django.conf.urls import url
    from . import views

    urlpatterns = [
        url(r'^$', views.IndexView.as_view(), name='index'),
        url(r'^(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/$', views.DetailView.as_view(), name='detail'),
        url(r'^(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/results/$', views.ResultsView.as_view(), name='results'),
        url(r'^(?P<question_id>[0-9]+)/vote/$', views.vote, name='vote')
    ]
```

Here is views.py:

```
    from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404
    from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
    from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse
    from django.views import generic

    from .models import Question, Choice

    class IndexView(generic.ListView):
        template_name = 'polls/index.html'
        context_object_name = 'latest_question_list'

        def get_queryset(self):
            return Question.objects.order_by('-pub_date')[:5]

    class DetailView(generic.DetailView):
        model = Question
        template_name = 'polls/detail.html'

    class ResultsView(generic.DetailView):
        model = Question
        template_name = 'polls/results.html'

    def vote(request, question_id):
        p = get_object_or_404(Question, pk=question_id)
        try:
            selected_choice = p.choice_set.get(pk=request.POST['choice'])
        except (KeyError, Choice.DoesNotExist):
            return render(request, 'polls/detail.html', {
                                 'question':p,
                            'error_message': "You didn't select a choice",})
        else:
            selected_choice.votes += 1
            selected_choice.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('polls:results', args=(p.id,)))
```

And here is index.html:

```
    {% if latest_question_list %}
        <ul>
        {% for question in latest_question_list %}
            <li><a href="{% url 'polls:detail' question_id %}">{{ question.question_text }}</a></li>
        {% endfor %}
        </ul>
    {% else %}
        <p>No polls are available.</p>
    {% endif %}
```

Answer (score 5):

Change this
 `{% url 'polls:detail' question_id %}` to  `{% url 'polls:detail' question.id %}`

Comment: Yep that was it. I feel stupid for not catching it, but happy that it was just something small and easy t fix like this. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

You are rendering `question` so to access its value it should be `question.value` not `question_value`:

user `{% url 'polls:detail' question.id %"`

where question.id is the numeric argument to the url.

Comment: Yeah, that was it.
Thank you sir.

Comment: @Exodus111 : If you find this as you answer you have to mark it with green tic. Always welcome